# How to use phone as microphone in linux

Tags: android, microphone, 22.10, pipewire

I am using Ubuntu 22.03 LTS currently and I want to know if there is any way to use android as microphone for Linux. I tried WoeMic but it didn't work. I tried following all the instruction in woeMic website,it even shows connected but I can't get any input.

I tried mic over mumble but it is too confusing for me. I got it working but I am not getting another input device in ubuntu settings.
I tried both of these things in both the latest ubuntu 24 and ubuntu 23 and 20 LTS . Thanks in advance : )

Comment: Use Droid Cam or follow the steps given in https://docs.audiorelay.net/instructions/linux/use-your-phone-as-a-mic-for-a-linux-pc only requisite is that your phone and pc should connected via same internet connection

Comment: did this help you??

Comment: Please be precise with details; are you asking about Ubuntu products? as you don't actually mention any. Ubuntu's main products are *year.month* in format; and there was no release in 2020-March (20.03), the 2024 releases (24.04, 24, 24.10) don't occur until 2024-April, 2024-July & 2024-October) which is in the future; 23.04 being the latest *snapshot* of where the 24.04 development is (two year development cycle has three non-LTS releases showing where LTS development currently is), and the *year* flavors are different to the more common *year.month* (ie. 20 is a flavor of 20.04 LTS Server)